# Is there a good reference for improving my penmanship?

Tags: handwriting, references

Over the years I've used the traditional Palmer method for writing different things. However I often developed confusion when trying to integrate this with mathematical formulas and other technical stuff.

During my high school, my writing was a mess, and not good looking. I ended up mixing my cursive with some [Vereinfachte Ausgangsschrift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vereinfachte_Ausgangsschrift), as I attended a German school for some time. I stayed with this method well into my university years but this didn't help me to improve my cursive.

I understand [iampeth](https://www.iampeth.com/lessons) offers lessons in how to write, but it's too ornate and not functional enough for the intended use which I have in mind.

Is there some reference which I could try? It doesn't matter if is for children. I don't intend to use any sophisticated instrument such as special nibs or anything, just something which can be used with all-purpose writing tool such a pencil, ball point pen or a fountain pen (which I use from time to time). Can someone help me with this?. It would help me to have something which has steps or guides.

I think the style at which I'm aiming is something similar to Palmer (and not too soft or too rounded such as Zaner Bloser or D'Nealian).

Answer (score 2):

Years ago, I drastically improved my handwriting using Rosemary Sassoon's well-named *Teach Yourself: Better Handwriting.*

The original version is out of print, but there is what looks to be an updated version called *Improve Your Handwriting (Teach Yourself)*.

It was very clear, simple and effective, and produced lasting changes. Its main focus is to show what is the basic foundational structure that makes each letter legible. After you master those, you can elaborate your own personal handwriting as much as you want. My handwriting still isn't as beautiful as I might have hoped, but it is very readable now, and it used to just be "chicken scratch."

Comment: It seems that this book regards itself as a repair manual rather than a book to learn how to write from the beginning, which I think it is okay. But since there isn't much available to see in previews it would be very nice to know by how much did it improved your skills?. In other words a before and after. Does it exist a similar options other than the book you mentioned?. Does it exist some trick in this process?. Something like not having the wrist very tense or not pressing very hard or perhaps writing on a level surface?.

Comment: My writing went from unreadable to legible. It even looks nice if I put some concentration into it.  The main trick of the book is that it breaks each letter down into the foundational structure that makes is readable. After you master that, you can elaborate your own handwriting as much as you want.